# Can a freestanding pool's poles be cut to accommodate sloped concrete?

Tags: pool, metal-cutting, pole

We have a "Bestway 24' x 12' x 52" Power Steel Frame Above Ground Rectangular Swimming Pool". We placed it on a slab and it is slanted away from the house.

Can the pool's poles be cut to level the pool out?

[image]

Comment: Caveat Emptor -- would have been a great idea to check level first and read the instructions about finding a level patch before buying.   Too late now, but if the pool is aligned so the short edge is on the slope, you may find living with a little tilt in the frame is easier than a major fix to the slab.

Comment: That pool is holding 30 tons of water.  You're really going to take a hacksaw to the structure?  I hope you're a qualified engineer...

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Based on the question, I take it that the slab is adjacent to the house.  If that's the case, slanting away from the house is a feature and it's probably not a good idea to try to 'fix' it.

Comment: What kind of slope are we talking about?  What's the approximate drop over 10 feet?

Comment: This just sounds dangerous to say the very least.

Comment: From [an online PDF manual](https://mcstaging.bestwayusa.com/media/pdf_files//56477E.pdf) from the manufacturer's web site: "The surface must be flat and smooth. If the surface is inclined or uneven, it can create an unbalanced loading on the structure of the pool. This
situation can damage the welding point of the liner and bend the frame. In the worst cases, the pool can collapse, causing serious personal
injury and/or damage to personal property.". and ...

Comment: ... "Follow the important instructions above to choose the correct surface and location to set up your pool. Damaged parts of the pool, due to the fact
that the set-up surface and location does not match the instructions, will not be considered as manufacture defect and will avoid [sic] the warranty and
any service claims."

Answer (score 28):

Yes, you probably could shorten the poles on the higher side. This might level the top edge of the pool*. However, think for a minute about what you're asking.

1. The bottom of the pool is sloped to match the concrete. You can't change this.
2. The surface of the water is level. You can't change this.
3. Cutting the poles will potentially lower the high side of the pool. *This doesn't change #1 or #2*. The only thing it changes is to lower the top of the pool wall with respect to the water level. Is this important?

**What are you trying to accomplish, exactly?**

<sub>* Side effects could be a wrinkle or pleat at the bottom of the wall and loss of tension resulting in lateral sag elsewhere (general misshapenness).</sub>

Comment: On a longer term view, if you cut the poles, then try to sell it or use it on a flat surface, your short poles will guarantee it won't work. A buyer isn't likely going to have the same surface as the OP does, so it'll be harder, if not impossible, to sell the pool. And for the same reason that it'll be hard to sell applies to having a new spot for the pool that is actually level. The poles will need to be replaced at an extra cost that could be avoided by just not cutting them in the first place.

Comment: @computercarguy the other issue with this is that the poles on the short side would need to follow the grade and based on the image, that seems problematic for a few reasons.

Answer (score 13):

The problem with cutting the poles is that the liner that goes inside won't fit like it's suppose to. Where the "shorter" poles are, part of the sides of the liner will be on the bottom of the pool. The sides are weaker the the bottom part of the liner and doing this could cause a leak. Your best bet would be to find out why the slab is slanted and do what you need to do to fix it. Temporarily leveling it off with a frame and sand would get you through the summer and then you could work on a permanent solution.

Comment: Most slabs against homes are sloped for drainage. There's nothing to fix.

Comment: @isherwood  Guess that depends on the slope. If it's a 1/8" per running foot patio slope, that's either a 3"  or 1.5" slant for the pool.  I doubt that's what they're worried about.

Comment: I don't. My patio has a similar slope and it results in a deformed pool.

Comment: I like the idea of a temporary sand base, though.

Comment: @isherwood  I guess the bottom line is that you adjusted to the deformed pool and didn't cut the legs. I'm thinking they have a more severe slope.

Answer (score 1):

Check the manufacturer's installation instructions for what the maximum supported slope/gradient is before you commit.

(**EXAMPLE NUMBERS**) I bet it is recommended to be installed on ground that is flat to within 2 degrees overall and contains no hollows or lumps, with a maximum slope of perhaps 5 degrees at which point the warranty is void, and the manufacturer is not liable for any failures of the product.

Of course trimming the top of poles off will also void the warranty, if that is important to you.